# Why do Python zipapps get slower the bigger they get?

Tags: python, zip, zipapp

I have a python zipapp (specifically, of [pdm](https://github.com/pdm-project/pdm)). When running from the filesystem, it takes around `0.300s` just to show the help page. However, with my zipapp, its `1s`. The zipapp is around 25 MB (it includes all of the dependencies).

Getting a file in an uncompressed zip should be almost as fast as reading it since there's an index to tell you where to go in the file to get there.

EDIT: I was able to reengineer my code to be able to be profiled with cProfile. It seems that the extra 0.6 seconds is spent with `compile`, but I'm not sure for what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out --- for whatever reason, zipimport doesn't look in `__pycache__` in the zip, so it recompiles the source files each time. Replacing the files with their corresponding `pyc` files work fine, and speeds up execution to normal module speed.